# More than one yes no question in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a script to assist in my daily job. I am having trouble using more than one Yes/No question in my PowerShell script. I know someone out there has already solved this problem or the answer is staring me in the face and I am not seeing it. Here is what I have so far.

```
$msg = 'Do you want display AD group memberships? [Y/N]'
do {
$response = Read-Host -Prompt $msg
if ($response -eq 'y') {
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $sid | select name  | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
 until ($response -eq 'n')


$adunlock = 'Do you want to unlock users AD account? [Y/N]'
do 
$response = Read-Host -Prompt $adunlock
if ($res -eq 'y') {
   Unlock-ADAccount -Identity samAccountName
}
until ($res -eq 'n')
until ($res -eq 'q')
}
```

The last } is where the script fails and informs me I am missing while or until keyword in do loop.
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: The `do` blocks (`do {}`) should be closed before its respective `until` or `while`. Also, you introduced `$res` in a condition before it is defined.

Comment: I see that now, can't believed I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my preferred way to take action based on read-host input. I like this because it will not allow you to exit until you provide a valid response (or keyboard interrupt). Also, as others have noted, you have a syntax error with a missing bracket. Still, I recommend this method because it makes it more clear what is happening in the decision process.

```
$message = 'Do you want display AD group memberships? [Y/N]'
do {
    $response = Read-Host -Prompt $message
    if ($response -eq 'y') {
        $validResponse = $true
        Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $sid | Select-Object name | Format-Table -AutoSize
    }
    if ($response -eq 'n') {
        $validResponse = $true
    }
} until ($validResponse -eq $true)

$message = 'Do you want to unlock users AD account? [Y/N]'
do {
    $response = Read-Host -Prompt $adunlock
    if ($response -eq 'y') {
        $validResponse = $true
        Unlock-ADAccount -Identity samAccountName
    }
    if ($response -eq 'n') {
        $validResponse = $true
    }
} until ($validResponse -eq $true)
```